# Determine programmatically the index in the solution of project- C#

Tags: c#, solution, visual-studio-project

The method [Solution.Projects.Index(Object index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projects.item.aspx) get an index of project as number.

I have the name of the project. How can I determine the index in the solution of this project programmatically?

Comment: It appears that you need to test Projects names in loop like in (MSDN)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/EnvDTE.Projects.aspx] (can't test from phone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use linq:

```
string yourProject = "ProjectName";
var query = Solution.Projects.Cast<Project>()
            .Select((p, i) => new { Name = p.Name, Index = i})
            .First(p => p.Name == yourProject).Index;
```

Comment: OP asked, how he could find "the index in the solution of this project", not the project itself, or am I missing something?

Comment: This code cause to the following error: 'EnvDTE.Projects' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'EnvDTE.Projects' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add `using System.Linq`, this is an extension method from `System.Linq.Enumerable`

Comment: The indexes of the projects start from 1, and this code return from 0, how should I change it to return the correct index?

Comment: Indexes in all collections start from 0, if you want you can add 1 to the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of the project, you could loop through all the projects to find the index of the desired project:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
{
    if (string.Equals(project.Name, "desired project name"))
    {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

On the other hand why do you actually need the index of the project? You can use [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projects.item.aspx) method with project name as parameter as well.

> The value passed to index is an integer that is an index to a Project object in its collection. **The value of index can alternatively be a string value that equates to the name of a project in the collection.**

Comment: Why string.Equals instead == ?

Comment: @PTwr, more explicit; plus you can additionally specify `StringComparison` parameter; plus habit.